# ClassNotFoundException from applet on Java 1.7u25 when certificate revocation check is enabled; working fine on 1.6

Tags: java, security, applet, classnotfoundexception, certificate-revocation

I'm using html & jnlp to deploy the applet. The applet is signed by externally generated certificate because it needs all-permissions. It works fine on Java 1.6. On Java 1.7 it throws ClassNotFoundException being unable to find applet's main class.

The code has been compiled using 1.6 and I need it working on both 1.6 and 1.7.

index.html:

```
<body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        var attributes = {
            code:'com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet', width:"100%", height:"100%"} ;
        var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'WebUI.jnlp'} ;
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
    </script>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

WebUI.jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
        <information>
                <title>WebUI</title>
                <vendor>Alcatel-Lucent</vendor>
        </information>
        <security>
                <all-permissions/>
        </security>
        <resources>
                <j2se version="1.6+"
                        href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
                <jar href="applet.jar"/>
                <jar href="log4j.jar"/>
        </resources>
        <applet-desc
                name="WebUI Applet"
                main-class="com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet"
                width="1200"
                height="900">
        </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Here's the content of Java console:

```
Java Plug-in 10.25.2.17
Using JRE version 1.7.0_25-b17 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\wolanski
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
basic: PluginMain.unregisterApplet: 10 from mananger sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager@1dc9fb9
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.25
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 2.2.25
network: Connecting https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/WebUI.jnlp with proxy=HTTP @ proxy-be.netsec.alcatel.fr/138.203.144.49:1080
network: ResponseCode for https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/WebUI.jnlp : 200
network: Encoding for https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/WebUI.jnlp : null
network: Server response: (length: 513, lastModified: Tue Jul 02 12:23:26 CEST 2013, downloadVersion: null, mimeType: application/x-java-jnlp-file)
network: Downloading resource: https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/WebUI.jnlp
    Content-Length: 513
    Content-Encoding: null
network: Wrote URL https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/WebUI.jnlp to File C:\Users\wolanski\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\34\1985a662-2cdb1fdd-temp
network: Disconnect connection to https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/WebUI.jnlp
network: Downloaded https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/WebUI.jnlp: C:\Users\wolanski\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\34\1985a662-2cdb1fdd
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/WebUI.jnlp
temp: new XMLParser with source:
temp: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>WebUI</title>
        <vendor>Alcatel-Lucent</vendor>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+"
            href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <jar href="applet.jar"/>
        <jar href="log4j.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
        name="WebUI Applet"
        main-class="com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet"
        width="1200"
        height="900">
    </applet-desc>
</jnlp>


temp: 

returning ROOT as follows:

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
  <information>
    <title>WebUI</title>
    <vendor>Alcatel-Lucent</vendor>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="applet.jar"/>
    <jar href="log4j.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <applet-desc name="WebUI Applet" main-class="com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet" width="1200" height="900"/>
</jnlp>
temp: returning LaunchDesc from XMLFormat.parse():

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/">
  <information>
    <title>WebUI</title>
    <vendor>Alcatel-Lucent</vendor>
    <homepage href="null"/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/applet.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/log4j.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
  </resources>
  <applet-desc name="WebUI Applet" main-class="com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet" documentbase="https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/" width="1200" height="900"/>
</jnlp>
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL2 called for https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/applet.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL2 called for https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/log4j.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.drainPendingURLs addURL called for https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/applet.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.drainPendingURLs addURL called for https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/log4j.jar
network: LaunchDownload: concurrent downloads from LD: 4
network: Total size to download: -1
network: Connecting https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/log4j.jar with proxy=HTTP @ proxy-be.netsec.alcatel.fr/138.203.144.49:1080
network: Connecting https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/applet.jar with proxy=HTTP @ proxy-be.netsec.alcatel.fr/138.203.144.49:1080
security: Security check for progress jars: allSigned=true
network: ResponseCode for https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/log4j.jar : 304
network: Encoding for https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/log4j.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/log4j.jar
network: Downloaded https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/log4j.jar: C:\Users\wolanski\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache404132370550332858.tmp
network: Download Progress: jarsDone: 1
network: ResponseCode for https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/applet.jar : 304
network: Encoding for https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/applet.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/applet.jar
network: Downloaded https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/applet.jar: C:\Users\wolanski\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache6586840229390565250.tmp
network: Download Progress: jarsDone: 2
network: Created version ID: 1.6+
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.25
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.25
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 2.2.25
basic: LaunchDesc location: https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/applet.jarjnlp
network: Created version ID: 1.0+
network: Created version ID: 7.0
security: Istrusted: null false
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: SHA-256 finger print: 85E41F40F62636715DA09BCF06388AD78253FEDD342F9D0F1468051C408C6F32
security: SHA-256 finger print: 2B2E6761A0B4501D1C0BE3E4EAA1EC2616D6378C2E50452ACF01E903C178A1DA
security: SHA-256 finger print: 8F712CFBB07A0B6E6C79856ACFE732B15297BED0A09C4BC7054D98D6D221E7A6
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: The OCSP support is enabled
security: The CRL support is enabled
security: Failing over to CRLs: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
network: Connecting http://services.support.alcatel-lucent.com/PKI/rootCA.crl with proxy=HTTP @ proxy-be.netsec.alcatel.fr/138.203.144.49:1080
network: Connecting http://services.support.alcatel-lucent.com/PKI/rootCA.crl with cookie "__unam=fc17cf9-13f0986907f-5c58b84b-2; SMSESSION=LOGGEDOFF; ADPSESSION=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; s_cc=true; s_fid=7850BE6AE5E29761-17B7DC4D6933DC7D; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D"
network: Connecting http://www.alcatel-lucent.com/PKI/rootCA.crl with proxy=HTTP @ proxy-be.netsec.alcatel.fr/138.203.144.49:1080
network: Connecting http://www.alcatel-lucent.com/PKI/rootCA.crl with cookie "__unam=fc17cf9-13f0986907f-5c58b84b-2; has_js=1; SMSESSION=LOGGEDOFF; ADPSESSION=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; s_cc=true; s_fid=7850BE6AE5E29761-17B7DC4D6933DC7D; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D"
security: Failing over to CRLs: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: SHA-256 finger print: 85E41F40F62636715DA09BCF06388AD78253FEDD342F9D0F1468051C408C6F32
security: SHA-256 finger print: 2B2E6761A0B4501D1C0BE3E4EAA1EC2616D6378C2E50452ACF01E903C178A1DA
security: SHA-256 finger print: 8F712CFBB07A0B6E6C79856ACFE732B15297BED0A09C4BC7054D98D6D221E7A6
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: The OCSP support is enabled
security: The CRL support is enabled
security: Failing over to CRLs: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
security: Failing over to CRLs: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: SHA-256 finger print: 85E41F40F62636715DA09BCF06388AD78253FEDD342F9D0F1468051C408C6F32
security: SHA-256 finger print: 2B2E6761A0B4501D1C0BE3E4EAA1EC2616D6378C2E50452ACF01E903C178A1DA
security: SHA-256 finger print: 8F712CFBB07A0B6E6C79856ACFE732B15297BED0A09C4BC7054D98D6D221E7A6
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: The OCSP support is enabled
security: The CRL support is enabled
security: Failing over to CRLs: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
security: Failing over to CRLs: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
network: Connecting http://localhost:389/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://www.alcatel-lucent.com/PKI/SSLsubCA.crl with proxy=HTTP @ proxy-be.netsec.alcatel.fr/138.203.144.49:1080
network: Connecting http://www.alcatel-lucent.com/PKI/SSLsubCA.crl with cookie "__unam=fc17cf9-13f0986907f-5c58b84b-2; has_js=1; SMSESSION=LOGGEDOFF; ADPSESSION=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; s_cc=true; s_fid=7850BE6AE5E29761-17B7DC4D6933DC7D; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D"
network: Connecting http://services.support.alcatel-lucent.com/PKI/SSLsubCA.crl with proxy=HTTP @ proxy-be.netsec.alcatel.fr/138.203.144.49:1080
network: Connecting http://services.support.alcatel-lucent.com/PKI/SSLsubCA.crl with cookie "__unam=fc17cf9-13f0986907f-5c58b84b-2; SMSESSION=LOGGEDOFF; ADPSESSION=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; s_cc=true; s_fid=7850BE6AE5E29761-17B7DC4D6933DC7D; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D"
security: Certificate validation succeeded using OCSP/CRL
security: Start comparing to jurisdiction list with this certificate
network: Connecting http://localhost:389/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: Certificate validation succeeded using OCSP/CRL
security: Start comparing to jurisdiction list with this certificate
network: Connecting http://localhost:389/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: Certificate validation succeeded using OCSP/CRL
security: Start comparing to jurisdiction list with this certificate
security: Mark trusted: null
basic: passing security checks; secureArgs:true, allSigned:false
basic: continuing launch in this VM
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet: try again ..
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: load: class com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ignored exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alu.ds.webui.applet.WebUIapplet
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: Loading Java Applet Failed...
security: Reset deny session certificate store
cache: MemoryCache: removed entry https://135.1.12.70:8590/WebUI/WebUI.jnlp
```

Comment: Did you produce -target 1.6 binary classes?

Comment: I'm building the code using eclipse, and then simply put the classes into a jar file like into a zip file. In eclipse compiler settings 1.6 is set.

Comment: Preferences / Java / Compiler / [_] Use default compliance settings / Generated class files compatibility [1.6].

Comment: I'll check that in a moment (I've built the code but need to wait for getting it signed). But is the setting in your comment different then "1.6" set as Compiler compliance level and Use default compliance settings checked?

Comment: I've tested the applet built with the settings you have proposed. The exception is the same and the console messages seem to be the same.

Comment: I've also tried manipulating "codebase" in applet's manifest. I tried both "*" and the <my-link> - no success. Do you think codebase may have something to do with this problem?

Comment: Not sure, but "compliance" reeks after `javac -source 1.6` and you need also `javac -target 1.6`. You can probably dump the .class with javap and check that the class version is less than 52 (Java 7).

Comment: Running javap on the main applet class gives: minor version: 0, major version: 50.

Please note that it's working fine on 1.6. The problem exists with 1.7.

Comment: Comparing 1.6 (working) coinsole output to the 1.7 (failing) I see that on 1.6 there's "basic: passing security checks; secureArgs:false, allSigned:false" entry, while on 1.7 there's "secureArgs:true"

Does it tell us anything?

Comment: The class version is right then, the security measures became a bit stricter on applets; but I cannot help there.

Comment: Try searching the [bug DB](http://bugs.sun.com/) & if you find nothing similar, raise a new report.  See what Oracle has to say on the matter.

Comment: Could you please help me to understand the bug DB issues handling process? Take a look at this one: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7153793. There's only one comment with some questions, no answers to them and then, after 3,5 months the ticket is closed without any explanation. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug back in 1.6u19, then it was solved and now it seems to be reintroduced in 1.7u25.

The solution is to add following line to the manifest:
Trusted-Library: true

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I had the exact same problem with my java application distributed with web-start, when upgrading from 1.7u45 to 1.7u51. Adding the Trusted-Library attribute in the manifest of the main jar fixed the problem.